# Query Store switches to ERROR, logs a message suggesting inconsistency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Today I have found 3 production databases writing this message to SQL Server logs :

*The Query Store in database XXX has an invalid structure for internal table plan_persist_plan, possibly due to schema or catalog inconsistency.*

DBCC CHECKDB runs daily. Today it did not find any inconsistency in all databases.
So I executed :

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE ('sys.plan_persist_plan')
```

which returns a similar output on all 3 impacted databases :

*DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_plan'.
There are 82193 rows in 1580 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_plan".
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.*

As all seems to be fine, I finish with :

```
ALTER DATABASE someDB SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR ALL
ALTER DATABASE someDB SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE)
```

Query Store is sized 2 to 5 GB, and configured with the very same options on all prod databases.

Does anyone encounter a similar issue ?
I see several messages in sys.messages about this :

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.messages
WHERE   text LIKE 'The Query Store%'
AND language_id = 1033
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error, including state.

Comment: The error number is 12429 its severity is 16. The message is found in SQL Server logs, so I don't have a state. The XXX above stands for the real name of the database, which I cannot share.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered that error in [another Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231650/how-can-i-export-query-store-data/231658#231658) where I manually inserted "invalid" data into the query store-related base tables using the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC).  The data was "invalid" because I was inserting query store data about object IDs that didn't exist in the target database.

Not that I think that specific thing is happening here.  That would be weird.

What I **am** saying is that I don't think the "inconsistency" mentioned in the error message necessarily indicates *corruption*.

**This is purely speculation**, but it's possible that similar inconsistencies could happen with schema changes happening at high concurrency, or if you have global trace flags 7745 and 7752 (reference: [Use Query Store in mission-critical servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16#Recovery) during such changes and a restart or failover occurs.

By the way, you mentioned

> The message is found in SQL Server logs, so I don't have a state.

You should typically see the state in the SQL Server logs.  It showed up in my test case from the linked Q&A:

> Error: 12434, Severity: 20, State: 56.
> The Query Store in database Sandbox is invalid, possibly due to schema or catalog inconsistency.